# after moving fregment is not loading

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]
[image]

I make an app using android studio and java but after I move between  fragment A to another fragment B then again move back to fragment A then it did  not load the  fragment A content

fragment overlapping in android studio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.